# Sharing wifi from mac to iphone

Tags: macbook-pro, iphone, wifi, sharing

I Googled how to do share my wifi connection from my Mac (new Macbook Pro)  to my iPhone (5S) and I tried their way.
System Preferences > Sharing > Internet Sharing
but then i don't have the same options they showed me.

I have share your connection from: Thunderbolt bridge, wi-fi, bluetooth PAN, and bluetooth DUN.

When I choose wifi, which is what I'm supposed to chose from what i've read, I only get two options in the to computers using: Thunderbolt bridge and bluetooth pan but no wifi and neither is working

All the other share you connection from options allow me to do so with computers using wifi thunderbolt bridge and bluetooth pan.

What should I do? Thanks

Comment: You can share your Ethernet / Thunderbolt connection or Bluetooth connection via wifi. You can't share your wifi connection via wifi. In other words, you can share the connection from one interface to another, but not through the same interface.

Comment: Oh alright. i Tried share your connection from thunderbolt bridge to computers using wifi and it still didn't work. i don't have the ethane option.

Comment: That's odd, Thunderbolt > Wifi should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please attach a screenshot?
You should have this screen in your sharing options (System Preference - Sharing):

[image: Sharing config]

[image: Sharing setup]

Comment: I'm new here so i am not sure how to attach a picture. 
i do have this. but in share your connection from i only have 4 options: 
wi-fi - thunderbolt bridge- bluetooth pan and bluetooth dun. 
which one should i choose? 
i tried share your connection with thunderbolt bridge to computers using wifi. i added a password and everything. then i tried to check the available network wifi on my iPhone but my mac didn't show up. what should i do? Thanks

Comment: How are you connected to the internet now? 
When already using WiFi to connect to the internet, it is not possible to share your internet connection through WiFi.

Answer (score 0):

This are the steps to share your Ethernet / Thunderbolt Ethernet internet connection through Wi-Fi:

- Make sure your Mac is connected to the internet via Ethernet / Thunderbolt ethernet. It should look something like this on Preferences > Network. The green dot to the left of the interface suggests it's correctly connected and has internet access. To make sure, you may turn Wi-Fi off and try to browse.
  [image: Thunderbird Ethernet connected]
- Go to Preferences > Sharing, and look to the right of the preferences window for "Share your connection from:" and select "Thunderbolt Ethernet" (or Ethernet if your mac has an ethernet port) in the drop-down menu to the right; below that it says "To computers using", check "Wi-Fi" on the list. This must be done **while Internet Sharing is off**, or you won't be able to change anything.

[image: Internet sharing Yosemite From - To]

- You can check the settings of the Wireless network you will be creating by clicking on <kbd>Wi-Fi Options...</kbd>

[image: Internet Sharing - Wi-Fi Options]

Here you set the

1. Network Name (the SSID, that will appear on the list when looking for Wi-Fi on the devices that connect to this network)
2. Channel, which you can leave as it is (choosing the right channel requires a whole other answer).
3. Security: WPA2 is recommended; "none" will allow anybody who can see your network to connect to it, which is **very insecure**
4. Password, where you will create a password with at least 8 characters, ideally not 12345678
5. Verify, where you will enter the same password again to be sure there are no typos.

---

- Activate Internet Sharing on the list to the left of the Sharing Preferences Pane. A warning should pop-up; if you are at home or connected directly to your ISP you *shouldn't* have problems, but check with them first. If you are inside a corporate network, better check with IT before sharing internet in this way.

[image: Internet sharing: warning]

- If you're sure you won't disrupt anything, activate Internet sharing by clicking <kbd>Start</kbd>

This is what it looks like when activated.

[image: Internet sharing Thunderbolt Ethernet > Wifi activated]

You should be able to find the Wi-Fi network on other devices.