# Enable wifi hotspot on Macbook Pro Mid 2014

Tags: macbook-pro, wifi

I am trying to share the internet connection from my MBP Mid 2014. It seems I can only share the internet through the Thunderbolt Bridge or Bluetooth PAN but I need it through the wifi for my Mobile device.

Is there any way I can share the internet connection through wifi ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's your outgoing connection? Ethernet/Thunderbolt? …or are you trying to share wifi whilst using wifi… which can't be done - see http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/192105/sharing-wifi-from-mac-to-iphone

Comment: @Tetsujin I am trying to share wifi whilst using wifi

Comment: then it can't be done - you have to go 'through' the machine, you cannot re-use the same interface for both 'ends' of the connection.

Answer (score 0):

You must select ethernet in the "share your connection from" 
after you must select Wi-fi in "To computers using"

Comment: MBP Mid 2014 version don't have a ethernet port. I only have 2 choices Thunderbolt or Bluetooth.

Comment: Ok. Select the Wi-fi option on the "share your connection form"

Comment: after select bluetooth in the "To computers using"

Comment: Let me know id you need another information